# Using OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications, then approve not registering

Tags: react-native, onesignal

I am user OneSignal in combination with React-Native to setup the push notifications. In my app, users need to be logged in, in order receive push notifications (or to give permission).

The issue that I am having, is that when the user logs in, they get my custom popup, asking if they would like to receive messages. If they click yes, they iOS popup shows, asking for permission.

When I click yes again, and check the OneSignal users dashboard, to see which users have registered for the push notifications. I see mine, but as opted out, which is not correct.

So I am wondering if there is a bug in the code of OneSignal (already in contact with them, but is going slow) or my code is wrong.

I am using;

- React-native 0.56
- react-native-onesignal: 3.2.7

The following code is what I currently have:

```js
componentWillMount() {
    OneSignal.init("{key}", {kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt : false});
    AsyncStorage.multiGet(['firstTime', 'subscribed']).then((response) => {
        this.setState({
            firstTime: JSON.parse(response[0][1]) != null ? JSON.parse(response[0][1]) : true,
            subscribed: JSON.parse(response[1][1]) != null ? JSON.parse(response[1][1]) : false
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !this.state.subscribed && this.state.firstTime) {
                OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
            }
        }, 200);
    });
    OneSignal.addEventListener('received', this.onReceived);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('opened', this.onOpened);
    OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', this.onIds);   
}
componentDidMount () {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
    AsyncStorage.getItem('firstTime').then((result) => {
        !this.isCancelled && this.setState({
            firstTime: JSON.parse(result) != null ? JSON.parse(result) : true
        })
    });

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (!this.state.subscribed && this.state.firstTime) {
                    Alert.alert(
                        I18n.t('notifications title'),
                        I18n.t('notifications subtitle'),
                        [
                            {text: I18n.t('notifications no'), onPress: () => {
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    AsyncStorage.multiSet([['firstTime', JSON.stringify(false)], ['subscribed', JSON.stringify(false)]]);
                                }, 100)
                            }, style: 'cancel'},
                            {text: I18n.t('notifications ok'), onPress: () => {
                                if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                                    OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
                                }else if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                                    // OneSignal.setLogLevel(6, 0);
                                    OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications();
                                }
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    AsyncStorage.multiSet([['firstTime', JSON.stringify(false)], ['subscribed', JSON.stringify(true)]]);
                                }, 100)
                            }}
                        ],
                        { cancelable: false }
                    )
                }
            }, 500)
        }else{
            OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
        }
        SplashScreen.hide();
    });
};
```

Hope you guys can help out.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I found the cause of the issue. The second setSubscription(false) in the else statement was unsubscribing even-though I didn't.

So removing the else is fixing it for me.